# Need to scroll from clicked div to top of browser window. Not to top of document, using Isotope Jquery

Tags: jquery-animate, position, jquery-isotope, scrolltop

Please take a look at my [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/camsyl/EA8tM/46/)

I am using jQuery Isotope plugin and I am having troubles using their [itemPositionDataEnabled](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/options.html#itempositiondataenabled) to be able to scroll from my clicked item to the top of whats currently visible in the browsers window.

With itemPositionDataEnabled I should be able to extract the x and y position of what ever item I'm requesting.  However mine does nothing at all....

```
var $this = $(this),
scrollTop     = $(window).scrollTop(),
itemPosition  = $this.data('isotope-item-position'),
itemPositionY = $this.itemPosition.y,
distance      = (itemPositionY - scrollTop);

$('html, body').stop().animate({
scrollTop: distance
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a plain and simple error in these two lines:

```
itemPosition = $this.data('isotope-item-position'), 
    itemPositionY = $this.itemPosition.y;
```

The second line should be:

```
itemPositionY = itemPosition.y;
```

Not sure if you're all the way there since it only seems to work on the way you want on the first click.

http://jsfiddle.net/EA8tM/90/